# Adding a indentation of each recursive call

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function using factorial. I think I have the code down but am having trouble with the indentation.

```
def factorial(number,step=0):
    step += 1 
    st = ""

    if number == 1:
        print("Step", step, ": %sreturn 1"%(st)
        return 1
    else:
        print("Step", step, ": %s%d*factorial(%d)"%(st,number,number-1))
        st = "\t"
        return number * factorial(number - 1, step)

Output:
Step 1 : 5*factorial(4)
Step 2 : 4*factorial(3)
Step 3 : 3*factorial(2)
Step 4 : 2*factorial(1)
Step 5 : return 1
```

The results I am needing are:

```
Step 1 : 5*factorial(4)
Step 2 :     4*factorial(3)
Step 3 :         3*factorial(2)
Step 4 :             2*factorial(1)
Step 5 :                 return 1
```

Comment: It is a bit ironic since you are learning about recursive functions - you should know that the `st` variable will be created every time you enter the function call and therefore will forever be `""`. You can fix that by changing the declaration to be `st = "\t" * step` (and also remove the `st = "\t"` line).

Comment: Ah, okay. I see what you mean. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @HenryPerez, I wrote what Yonlif explained as an answer, you should accept it to mark it as a working one. Welcome to Stack Overflow anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to remove

```
st = "\t"
```

otherwise each time the indentation will be the same.

---

Try this instead:

```
st = "\t" * step
```

so that you will have `step` indentation levels each time.

Comment: Right, step is already incrementing... should I edit the answer to be correct, or I should better delete it to let you write yours?